# How to remove rows in Pandas DF where value from Column A is in Column B and Column C Match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with some user/file information. For example:

```
| Scanned_Item | Matched_Item | Owner_Name |
|      item 1  |     item 2   |    owner 1 |
|      item 1  |     item 3   |    owner 1 |
|      item 3  |     item 1   |    owner 2 |
```

I have a few thousand items. It is possible for the Matched_Items to not be a Scanned_Item. What I'm trying to do is remove all rows where both Scanned_Item and Matched_Item are owned by the same person.

My desired output is a DF where no owner is matching with his own items, thus removing self duplication. I only want to see the rows where the owner is matching somebody else's file.

Equivalent to saying if Matched_Item exists in Scanned_Item and Owner_Name for Matched_Item = Owner_Name for Scanned_Item.

(The match is formed based on other predetermined criteria that aren't really relevant to this issue.

Edit: This is what I have written out now but it is taking forever, not sure if that's a sign that it's not working ha.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        if row['Scanned_Workbook'] == row2['Matched_Workbook'] and row['Full Name'] == row2['Full Name']:
            df.drop(index,errors='ignore')
            df.drop(index2,errors='ignore')
```

Edit2: As an added detail, since it seems there are some clarity issues. All Scanned and Matched items came from the same original data source. I found the Matched items by iterating my original data set and using Python set comprehension to find files where three criteria matched.

So item 1 was scanned and matches 3 criteria with item 2, that's where the first row comes from. But because of how I did the comprehension, I only have the owner name for the Scanned_Items, not the Matched_Items.

I am trying to remove all rows where the Scanned_Item and Matched_Item are both owned by the same Owner.

Does this help for clarity?

Edit3: Here is an example of rows that would be deleted.

```
| Scanned_Item | Matched_Item | Owner_Name |
|      item 1  |     item 2   |    owner 1 |
|      item 2  |     item 1   |    owner 1 |
```

Because both item 1 and 2 were scanned at some point, they matched with each other. But they also have the same owner. I want to remove ANY rows that look like this.

Owner name is tied to scanned item. So the only way I can find the owner of the matched item is if it shows up in the scanned column.

Comment: Have a look at `.apply`, maybe `.iterrows` or `itertuples`. If you need help I can post a quick example.

Comment: I'm familiar with iterrows, but not sure what the syntax/setup would be to compare two columns using it would be..

Comment: You write : `Equivalent to saying if Matched_Item exists in Scanned_Item and Owner_Name for Matched_Item = Owner_Name for Scanned_Item.`. You mean this condition concerns one row, or all the DataFrame ?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Can you explain a bit deeper? (you can answer Catalina's comment)

Comment: This applies for the entire dataframe. I am trying to match files based on certain criteria. The scanned and matched lists/series come from a Python set comprehension. It gives me all files where three or more certain categories match. And I do not want to see rows where any owner is matching his own file.

Comment: I updated my answer, hoping it may help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you need to delete duplicates.

Why not simply write the following, if you want to delete all those rows:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

If you want to keep at least one of the duplicates, just change the valeu of the argument:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Comment: ya, but it seems operation is per groups of owners

Comment: @jezrael : If it is per group of owners, one should make a groupby before. But even in this case, things must be clarified by the author and especially: which rows will be kept and which will be deleted, as considered duplicate ? This is ambiguous.

Comment: I think the rows to be deleted are those where matched and scanned item are the same owner. I think you either map each item to each owner, or you do a self join, and filter the rows with the boolean mask that comes out of it

Comment: @jezrael: In fact it seems he wants to delete all those rows, not keeping one, according to the description of the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Disregard this comment, bad formatting. Will add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the task in two steps

1. map each `item` to its `owner`
2. apply a boolean mask to filter
   based on step 1

Step 1: map `owners` to `items`.
We could do this with a dictionary.
Assuming `Matched_Item` is the item associated with `Owner_Name`,

```
df_owner_items = df[["owner_name", "matched_item"]].          \
                     drop_duplicates().                       \  # We select only non duplicated records
                     set_index("matched_item")                \  # We set index to use the `from_dict` method later in the most useful way
owner_items_dict = df_owner_items.to_dict(orient="index")        # Our dataframe is transformed in a dictionary having format {"item1": {"owner_name": "owner 1"}}
```

Step 2: create boolean mask and filter

```
filter = (df["owner_name"] != owner_items_dict["matched_item"]["owner_name"])
filtered_df = df.loc[filter]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Went a different route to solve the issue. I just joined back the original data set and found the owner of the matched_items so I could have both scanned and matched owners in separate columns. Then, using df.query, removed all the rows where the two owner values matched.

This resolved my issue, thank you for everyone who answered/commented.